# Sharing state between Cucumber Steps

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, bdd

What is a good pattern to follow when sharing state between steps in Cucumber when using Ruby? Is using a simple @variable the recommended approach?

Comment: Using instance variables is typically how I've seen it done.  If you post a minimal code example, you'll likely get more specific answers.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164255/how-to-share-state-between-scenarios-using-cucumber

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That was about sharing state between scenarios, this is about sharing state between steps.

Comment: I have always used instance variables.  Occasionally when there are lots of things to move around I'll use a dto as the instance variable and put all of the other things inside it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve variable in cucumber?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962439/preserve-variable-in-cucumber)

Comment: Greg, that answer explains two ways to get it working. I am asking if there are any good patterns to use. This is beyond just getting it working.